# What is $Δf=ρ$ in Physics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential

I asked a while ago a question on mathoverflow. It was a mathematical question with physical implications. To cut the story short, one mathematician said that Classically, a potential satisfies $$Δf=ρ$$, but when I asked him about what does each variable stand for, I did not get an answer. So, I am hoping I get one here. Where do we see this $Δf=ρ$ in physics and what does each variable stand for?

Comment: This is Poisson's equation and it pops up in many areas. Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson's_equation

Comment: Should there be a minus sign?

Comment: Which Q on mathoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

$\Delta$ is the Laplacian, the sum of second derivatives. It is applied to a function $f$ of the spatial coordinates which you typically want to solve for. $\rho$ is some given function of the spatial coordinates.

As mentioned by Martin, Poisson's equation has a multitude of applications throughout most of physics. A cornerstone example is electrostatics where it takes on the form $\Delta \phi = -\rho/\varepsilon_0$ where one seeks the electrostatic potential $\phi(\vec x)$ given a certain charge density distribution $\rho(\vec x)$. $\varepsilon_0$ is the vacuum permittivity.

Comment: The Laplacian does not always contain just second derivatives, e.g. the Laplacian in polar coordinates on $\mathbb R^2$ is $\Delta \sim \partial_{\theta \theta} + \partial_{rr} + \partial_r$. Also, if you look at the generalisation known as the Laplace-Beltrami operator, you can get more than just second derivatives in most cases.

Comment: Sure, my above statement applies to cartesian coordinates only. However, $\Delta=\nabla^2$ is a second order differential operator.